# What is the purpose of declaring class that extends any - Typescript

Tags: typescript, class

I am looking at a code in package called WalletConnect and I encountered one strange thing there. In declaration file, there are these two lines:

```
declare const ProviderEngine: any;
declare class WalletConnectProvider extends ProviderEngine {
    bridge: string;
    ...
}
```

Why would one create the class that extends `any`? What is this good for? Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all that does is allow autocompletion for known properties, while still allowing any property.

For example you get this autocompletion:

[image: class autocomplete]

Even though anything is allowed, since the class extends `any`.

```
new WalletConnectProvider().bridge // can autocomplete this property
new WalletConnectProvider().noSuchMethod() // no type error
```

however, I would not recommend this as almost all uses of `any` lower type safety. And in this case you could write all kinds of code that would crash at runtime. I'm not really sure what the author of these was trying to do, but this just seems like a bad plan.

Comment: Yes, it seemed almost useless for me as well regarding the type safety. Thank you! :)